# how to have a smaller grails 3 war

Tags: grails

I created a grails 3 application with the profile rest-api, hoping that the war will be smaller (since it won't include all the gsp related jars)

But I see that the war for a very small application is still 63 MB

Is there anyway to make the wars smaller in grails 3 ?

Comment: Is there any unwanted dependency, plugins in the project that increase the size of war?

Comment: I only added the websocket plugin, the others are what comes with the rest api profile. this is why i feel it's strange

Comment: How are you building the war?

Comment: Simply `Grails war`